# Exiting a thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Thread som;    
static  class solver implements Runnable  {                                 
       public void distancecalculator(char [][]problem , Point start , 
       int distancefound) {
       // Some code and condition to exit from program if satisfy 
       solver s = new solver(newproblem , neworigin,dist[a][b] );
       som =  new Thread(s);
       som.start();
    }

    public void run(){                  
       //som.sleep(1000);
       //System.out.println("check");
       distancecalculator(prom,movepoint ,disadd ); //Making a recursive call                       
    }
```

I am generating threads on every recursive call, I want that in control way i.e. if 500 threads are generated then terminate the first 100 threads. How can i achieve this? If i use `som.sleep` which thread will sleep the newly generated one or old one?

Comment: Have those threads check whether they ought to exit.

Comment: yes they have checked i want to terminate them

Comment: If they are already checking, why don't you write them so they terminate themselves?

Comment: how since they have all same name , after 500 threads i want to terminate 100 threads

Comment: First: Why are you using threads?

Answer (score 2):

1. `sleep` is a static method. It makes the calling thread sleep. More generally, there is no direct way to make another thread do anything, including sleep. You need a specific inter-thread communication mechanism for any such task.
2. Make a thread end by following the rules of the *interruption* mechanism (consult the documentation for `Thread#interrupt()` and `Thread#isInterrupted()`.

Comment: how should i check if threads are more than 500 then terminate 100 threads as it affect my program performance

Comment: as you can see after making a recursive call the new threads is generated so there is no need for previous one

Comment: Checking that there are 500 threads requires a solution which is not specific to multithreading. Treat the `Thread` instances as just a regular Java object, put them into a `Collection` and process the collection using  general-purpose collection-processing code. Use the method `Thread#isAlive()` to check that a thread is still running.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and create poll of n threads using [Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) factory method.

Find the example code in the above link and [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1069/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor) as well.

Comment: where i should create Executors in my main function or in class would you explain it with my code !! i am little bit confused

Comment: Just follow the links to find the tutorial on it.

Comment: this method will work if n threads have completed their task i want irrespective they have completed or not i want to terminate them.

Comment: what's the purpose of terminating the threads before finishing the task? What do you want to achieve? There is one more method `pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to wait a while for existing tasks to terminate.